# Running Scala Spec getting Error ..could not find implicit value for parameter ta

Tags: scala, akka, spray, scalatest, specs2

I have someTrait that extends Actor ( becuase it using some actor ref inside)

```
trait DemoService extends Actor {

  def actorRefFactory = context
  implicit def executionContext = actorRefFactory.dispatcher

  val demoRoute = {
    get {
      pathSingleSlash {
        complete(index)
      } ~
      path("ping") {
        complete("PONG!")
      }
```

Now I am Writing Spec file for same.

```
TestServiceSpec extends FlatSpec with Spec2RouteTest with DemoService
```

gettting error

```
could not find implicit value for parameter ta: TestServiceSpec 
.this.TildeArrow[spray.routing.RequestContext,Unit]"
```

If I use `ScalaTestRouteTest` also I get this error.

Comment: @Aleksey Izmailov pls help

Comment: @Andreas Neumann help pls